# How to begin Ghostwriting Fiction?

Tags: fiction

I'm a non-fiction ghostwriter wanting to ghostwrite fiction for others, what are some of the places I can find such work?

Comment: Have you ghostwritten fiction before? If so, try going through the same channels you used to get that work. If not, the only real way to do that would be to have published fiction yourself, in which case your agent would be the person to consult.

Comment: have ghostwritten a lot of nonfic but not fiction. i have no agent.

Comment: What market does something like this serve? I understand ghostwriting in non-fiction where someone has a life story or purposed exposition to express, but not the skills/time to tell it, but how does this work for fiction?

Answer (score 4):

I *have not* ghostwritten before, but I have received offers. All of them, without exception, were from old men with a high social standing who sought to establish themselves in a way or another. Some of them were judges and lawyers, good ones, and wanted to get a reputation as fiction writers. Some of them were academics who stopped writing a long time ago and had been hiring ghost writers for decades.

I became a *protegé* of an established writer and that's how I met most of these men. He vouched for my trustworthiness and skill, and that's how I received some of these offers. So, if you are looking for ghost writing offers, I recommend that you try to get inside the circles of writers where you live. Try to make friends with them, sometimes share your writing. Try and discover where the old rich men spend their time, normally there's a coffeehouse or library where they chat. Participate in your local university's academic life, go to the events from the Languages Department.

Do you know Bloomsday? Some of my potential clients took part in it once or twice. If your university has one, go to it.

Now, let me offer some words of advice for you. People looking for a ghost writer seek trustworthy, discreet writers. You've got to know how to keep a secret, or at least make it look like you know how to. Also, *if you do get into ghost writing*, remember that your clients are not necessarily trustworthy or nice people. Keep your distance, be ethical and professional, obey deadlines and don't mix work with personal life.

Good luck.